# csv.reader module in Python first shows null rows after header

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am new to Python and am running into a weird problem. I am working on automating the generation of a chart. It is a csv file produced by a piece of equipment, same format, same filename, every time.

I have it set up as follows:

- User selects folder location for file location and saving
- read and store X and Y variables for later
- Proceed to make line chart (omitted -- for example I just have it printing)

Everything was fine until looking for a file that had not previously been opened on my machine. 
I received a *"_csv.error line contains null byte"* error when the file was supposed to start reading. The header row is fine but there is no data. I double check the file by opening the csv in PyCharm and sure enough, there is no data. I open in excel, there is data. If I close without saving, there is still no readable data via this script. If I save then close, suddenly it works.

Is there a reason I have to open the file first before it will read? Is there a better module I can use? Like I said, I'm new to this and csv.reader is all I have been playing with to date. Well, I tried one of the excel ones but that was a tragedy LOL I can for sure make this work, but for the end user, its better to search for the file.

File used is a 4 column csv file where i use column 2 (real numbers) and column 4 (time of event).

```
import csv

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

from datetime import datetime

# Open dialogue to get desired folder destination
dialogue_prompt = "Choose the location of your file: \nIt will save as an image to the same directory."
print(dialogue_prompt)

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()

# Get Variable for Chart Title and Save Name
prompt = "\n\nEnter the title name for this chart and press Enter."
prompt += "\nNote: The chart title will also be the filename"
prompt += "\n --> "
current_chart_title = input(prompt)



# Open csv file and get Pressure and Time from RUNDATA
filename = file_path + '/' + 'RUNDATA.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    # create pressure and time lists
    y_val, x_val_time = [], []
    for row in reader:
        y_val.append(row[1])

        x_val = datetime.strptime(row[3], '%H:%M:%S')
        x_val_time.append(x_val)

print(y_val,x_val_time)
```

Comment: Try `with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f: reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')`

Comment: This did not work. I get the same error as soon as it steps into the for loop.

Comment: Which line generates the error? `reader = csv.reader(f)` or `header_row = next(reader)` or the for loop?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the output of `with open(filename, 'rb') as f:; print(f.read(100))`.

Comment: It would help if we could see the actual file. If possible add a link to the file for us to be able to download it.

Comment: I can upload a randomized test file later but in regards to @aneroid, the program actually stops at 'for row in reader'. Until i open the csv file and save it, the reader is not seeing any data.

Comment: I also tried the solution from @stovfl and the error occured this time at the `header_row = next(reader)`. It said the "iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)"

Comment: @Krys: **Not** a solution, should show your Data form the CSV so we can examine the behavior. But if you don't want to be helpful doing so we can't help.